# Selenium, start the find element from the bottom of the page

Tags: c#, selenium

In selenium, can you make the findElement function start from the bottom of the page?

```
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("Has Text"); // Need this to start the search from the bottom to the top.
```

I am using c#.

Comment: I don't think there's any order guarantee at all, it would depend on the driver implementation, and there's a lot of things that might impact the order even if you usually see a top-down order. Why not just iterate the list backwards?

Comment: @TamirDaniely Good idea, but this will waste alot of resources. I just want to grab the first most item i want on the bottom.

Comment: how do you know its not starting from bottom of the page ?

Comment: @PDHide Because when I output to console, it prints from the top of the page to bottom

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript if you read this there is two methods ordered and unordered

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Location-Steps this explains how it works , it  is from top down from context node

Comment: @Juansdk It will not waste "a lot of resources", it's just the same loop backwards.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is written in Java, but it's not a big deal to transform into C#.
Just get all needed elements, then trace it backwards by for-loop (or simply get the last one) and do whatever you need:

```
// tracing thru all

     List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("123"));
     for (int i = elements.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
       elements.get(i);
     }

// getting the last one

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("123"));
    elements.get(elements.size()-1);
```